# Samba server wrongly treated some files as folders

Tags: samba

Samba 4.11.7 under Fedora 31.

The shared folder contains 1300+ music files.
They can be displayed and played correctly on the Fedora host,
and they have the same ACL settings.
However, if I access the shared directory from Windows 10 computers,
most of (not all) the music files become "folders" and cannot be accessed,
causing "invalid handle" error.

[image]

On the Fedora host,
I tried to copied/moved these files to another folders, but it did not help.
Is it a bug of the 4.11.7 version of Samba?

Update:

I tried to access the shared folder from another Fedora 31 computer.
The result was exactly the same, turned out to be a problem of the Samba server.
[image]

Comment: Is it just `.flac` files that are appearing as folders?

Comment: Does Windows recognise local .flac files correctly?

Comment: To David. not all .flac files appear as folders. 29 flac files can be correctly recognized under Windows 10.

Comment: To Tetsujin. Yes. Actually I tested on 2 Windows 10 computers. The output file lists are exactly the same. Out of 1304 music files, only 55 can be recognized normally.

Answer (score 0):

Today I upgraded Fedora 31 to 32.

During that procedure, the Samba was upgraded to 4.12.1.

Everything works fine now.